# Get which checkbox inside ListView is checked when inflated dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have this listview:

```
            <ListView x:Name="listview_brouch" HasUnevenRows="true" Grid.Row="1">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                
                                <Label 
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Padding="0,10,0,10"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                    FontFamily="ButtonFont"
                                    Text="{Binding title}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    />

                                <CheckBox
                                     CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"  
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Color="Aqua"/>

                            </Grid>
                            

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

It consists of a label and a checkbox. I am giving the listview data like so:

```
    private void FillLists()
    {
        List<SubCategories> brouch = new List<SubCategories>();

        foreach (var e in subCategories)
        {
            if(e.IDfromCategories == categories[0].mainCategoryID)
                brouch.Add(e);
        }

        listview_brouch.ItemsSource = brouch;

    }
```

Now the list gets inflated by how many items there are in `brouch`

I now also inflate as many checkboxes as there are items in `brouch`

Now I can add an Eventhandler like I did to the checkbox.

However, every checkbox is the same. I need to know to which item from the corresponding object `brouch` the checkbox has been ticked.

Say there are thre items in `brouch`

ITEMNAME 1
ITENNAME 2
ITENNAME 3

And when I check checkbox 3 I need to know that this was coming from the row in the listview that also included ITEMNAME 3.

How do I achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `BindingContext` of the `sender`

```
protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  var check = (Checkbox)sender;
  var item = (SubCategories)check.BindingContext;

  // then item contains the object for the given row
}
```